# помогите найти и вывести найменший элемент матрицы и его индексы

Tags: javascript

```js
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const innerArr = [];

  for (let j = 0; j < deep; j++) {
    let colName = `column - ${i+1}x${j+1}`,
     item = prompt('insert item in' + colName);

    innerArr.push(+item);
  }
  result.push(innerArr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Удачи вам, когда преподаватель спросит, как это работает.

```js
const matrix = [
  [73,2,45,36,],
  [66,-45,45,97,],
  [128,755,11,94,],
  [0,150,-88,12,],
];
const min = array => Math.min.apply(null, array);
console.log(min(matrix.map(min)));
```

С индексами:

```js
const matrix = [
  [73,2,45,36,],
  [66,-45,45,97,],
  [128,755,11,94,],
  [0,150,-88,12,],
];

console.log(matrix.reduce((result, row, index) => {
  const minInRow = Math.min(...row);
  if(result.min > minInRow) result = {min: minInRow, row: index, col: row.indexOf(minInRow)};
  return result;
}, {min: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY})
);
```

Comment: плохой,плохой  пользователь

Comment: @YuriyZhulinskiy да, действительно, про индексы то я и забыл.. момент

Comment: @YuriyZhulinskiy обновил ответ, теперь индексы тоже в наличии.